# Preserving aspect ratio in a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to implement responsive grid containing 3x4 elements. I'm also using a bitmap image for each cell so I would like to preserve the aspect ratio of each cell. The problem I'm having now, is that my CSS doesn't prevent it from overflowing the vertical size of the viewport. It works fine when scaling on the horizontal axis.

**Works as expected:**
[image: Works as expected]

**Doesn't work as expected (creates a scrollbar):**
[image: Doesn't work as expected]

Link to CodePen: http://codepen.io/ekulabuhov/pen/JEyxby?editors=1100

```css
.container{
  height:100vm; width:100vm; /* IE9 fallback */
  width: 100vmin; height: 100vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;
}

.gametile {
  background: url('http://adrianpayne.me/game/assets/images/grass.png') no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;

  /* 33.3vmin; */
  width: calc(100vmin/3);
  float:left;
  height: calc(100vmin/3*(91/70));
  margin-top: -16vmin;
}


/*** FOR THE DEMO **/
body,html {margin:0;background:#123752;color:#fff;}
a{color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>

  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  height:100vm; width:100vm; /* IE9 fallback */
  width: calc(((100vmin - 16vmin) / 4 + 16vmin) * (70 / 91) * 3);
  height: 100vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;
}

.gametile {
  background: url('http://adrianpayne.me/game/assets/images/grass.png') no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;

  /* 33.3vmin; */
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  float:left;
  height: calc((100% - 16%) / 4 + 16%);
  margin-bottom: -16vmin;
}


/*** FOR THE DEMO **/
body,html {margin:0;background:#123752;color:#fff;}
a{color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>

  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
  <div class="gametile"></div>
</div>
```

Don't know if it works in IE9, but I fixed it for you. It probably won't work in IE anything. You can also try `display: grid` if you give up on older browsers.

Comment: Thank you! I've solved the problem with some hacky JS already. But your solution seems to be working very well too.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the values and managed to center it on the center of the screen without going out of bound.

```
.container{
  height:60vm; width:100vm; /* IE9 fallback */
  width: 100vmin; height: 60vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;


}

.gametile {
  background: url('http://adrianpayne.me/game/assets/images/grass.png') no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;

  /* 33.3vmin; */
  width: calc(80vmin/3);
  float:left;
  height: calc(80vmin/3*(91/70));
  margin-top: -16vmin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David! Appreciate your help! But it seems like your answer is creating left and right margin by limiting the width to `calc(80vmin/3)`. I would like to avoid that.